# URL redirection in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, routes

I need help in url redirection in codeigniter,

I have following url

http://test.com/MyProject/My13d2lnbGlsZGNtcWt0Z2w=

When I click above url, then it should redirect to my function like,

http://test.com/MyProject/api/TestingManagement/getMyUrl/My13d2lnbGlsZGNtcWt0Z2w=

We can do it with CI routes or .htaccess, but how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For Routes you can write following as last rule:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'api/TestingManagement/getMyUrl/$1';
```